# How to call back live wallpaper preview layout

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

In livewallpaper it has two button setting and set . When I click button setting it will call preference screen . I want to come back to livewallpaper preview screen when I click any item in preference screen . How can I do it . Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing to CubeLiveWallpaper example from sample android code, add following code to CubeWallpaper2Settings.java

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    finish();
}
```